# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning with nodejs and mysql Please let me know what is the problem

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

```
(node:15157) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'transaction_date' in 'where clause'
at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/home/jigyasoo/Documents/Gaurav's Folder/CocoCoala/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:47:14)
at Query.ErrorPacket (/home/jigyasoo/Documents/Gaurav's Folder/CocoCoala/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:79:18)
at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/jigyasoo/Documents/Gaurav's Folder/CocoCoala/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:291:23)
at Parser._parsePacket (/home/jigyasoo/Documents/Gaurav's Folder/CocoCoala/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
at Parser.write (/home/jigyasoo/Documents/Gaurav's Folder/CocoCoala/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
at Protocol.write (/home/jigyasoo/Documents/Gaurav's Folder/CocoCoala/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/jigyasoo/Documents/Gaurav's Folder/CocoCoala/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/jigyasoo/Documents/Gaurav's Folder/CocoCoala/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
--------------------
at Pool.query (/home/jigyasoo/Documents/Gaurav's Folder/CocoCoala/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:199:23)
at Promise (/home/jigyasoo/Documents/Gaurav's Folder/CocoCoala/util/async_db_call.js:5:14)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at module.exports (/home/jigyasoo/Documents/Gaurav's Folder/CocoCoala/util/async_db_call.js:4:12)
at main (/home/jigyasoo/Documents/Gaurav's Folder/CocoCoala/jobs/dailyjobs.js:98:33)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jigyasoo/Documents/Gaurav's Folder/CocoCoala/jobs/dailyjobs.js:299:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
```

(node:15157) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15157) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Unknown column 'transaction_date' in 'where clause' ??  seems you have a wrong column name

Comment: can you show a little bit more of the code? The error is pointing at line 4 of `async_db_call.js` and line 299 of `dailyjobs.js`

Comment: @vleonc thanks man, it got it.